# Unable to connect to mongodb Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112

Tags: mongodb

When ever I try to connect to mongo db I always get this error as below.

MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
Fri Apr 26 14:31:46.941 JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
exception: connect failed

I tried various solutions listed in stackoverflow and tried following commands but nothing works.

1) sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock

// says such file located at this place.

2)  sudo service mongodb start

// error: sudo: service: command not found

3) I've made sure nothing else is running at that port.

4) Even tried uninstalling and installing it again.

5) Also tried kill pid

Comment: Why don't you start mongodb first?

Comment: the fact service command fails means your distribution may use a different init system, you should at least specify what is your distribution, or at least try the init script located in /etc/init.d/ with name mongodb or something, so sudo /etc/init.d/mongodb start or similar

Comment: This solved it for me: https://gist.github.com/adamgibbons/cc7b263ab3d52924d83b

Answer (score 38):

Same error here, this worked for me:

```
sudo mongod --repair
```

followed by

```
sudo mongod
```

(forget about *service* and *start*)

Then on a different tab/terminal:

```
mongo
```

Answer (score 5):

Start mongod server first

```
mongod
```

Open another terminal window

Start mongo shell

```
mongo
```

Answer (score 4):

This is due to locking of Mongodb
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
sudo service mongodb restart

Answer (score 3):

Please Start the MongoDB server first and try to connect.

**Pre-requisite:**

Create space for storing DB and tables in any directory
Example `(windows): D:\mongodbdata\`

**Steps:**

1. Start server

   > mongod --port 5000 --dbpath D:\mongodbdata\   (please mention above created path)
2. Connect mongodb server (Run in another terminal/console)

   > mongo --port 5000

Answer (score 3):

If any one is facing the problem in windows machine then follow the steps.

1. Add the path of mongodb in the environmental variable.
2. Create a directory C:\Data\db.
3. Open a terminal(cmd) and write mongod. (it will initiate the server).
4. Open another terminal and write your own code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, In my case there was a mismatch of ipaddress in mongo config

```
~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: test
2015-02-02T17:48:52.302+0530 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-02-02T17:48:52.303+0530 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

When I checked my configuration file, I have specified the bind address to eth0 ip(10.8.10.111) not loopback address(127.0.0.1), So I have changed the ip address to loopback as like `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` in /etc/mongod.conf file and restart it with `service mongod restart`, finally works

```
# mongo 
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.7
connecting to: test
>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced same issue, my understanding is(it could be wrong)
 1. Make sure **mongodb is up and running**
 2. For linux access as sudo and for windows if connecting localhost turning off firewall may help but its not necessary
 3. Just **type mongo**, it will try to connect to localhost by default. You need to specify IP if you are connecting to a remote server. By default **test** db will be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
mongod --configsvr --smallfiles --nojournal --dbpath cfg/1 --port 26052 --fork --logpath cfg/3.log >/dev/null
```

## Create a single mongos server on the default port

```
sleep 2000
mongos --configdb ${HOSTNAME}:26050,${HOSTNAME}:26051,${HOSTNAME}:26052 --fork --logpath mongos.log >/dev/null
```

Sleep for some time before starting the mongos you will not face the problem

Answer (score 1):

First start `mongod` service then `mongo` or `mongos`

Answer (score 0):

If you create `data\db` folder, firstly you must delete this folder then execute:

```
c:\mongodb\bin\mongo.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix: I have the same problem to start the MongoDB and it was
easily fixed by running the file `mongod.exe` (`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`) then run the file `mongo.exe`
(`C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.2\bin`)..Problem fixed

Answer (score 0):

Mongo DB requires space to store it files. So you should create folder structure for Mongo DB before starting the Mongodb server/client.

for e.g. MongoDb/Dbfiles where Mongo DB is installed.

Then in cmd promt exe mongod.exe and mongo.exe for client and done.

Answer (score 0):

I met with this problem too. And I figured it out by the following way:

First, open the terminal and write

```
mongod --dbpath {your project's path}
```

Second, open a new terminal and enter your project's path, write

```
mongo
```

Then it runs successfully

Answer (score 0):

with new version of mongodb, this issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue until i close `teamviewer` running on my pc. Then it worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

I am using version 4.0.6 ( the current release) on Linux Mint. You need to install Mongodb Compass(mongodb GUI) to interact with your databases.
Here is the link: https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/install/

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on unix-like systems.

Starting in MongoDB 4.4, a startup error is generated if the ulimit value for number of open files is under 64000.
View the current val

```sh
$ ulimit -n
```

Change value

```sh
$ ulimit -n <val>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by changing the port in /etc/mongod.conf file then by running: mongo --port