# Node.js connect to MongoDB throw an error :MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to use node.js to connect with mongodb on my windows system. However, it throw me an error:

```
C:\Users\mazic\Dropbox\Information System\CS602 Server Site Web Development\MongoDB_Practice\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:225
          throw err
          ^
MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mazic\Dropbox\Information System\CS602 Server Site Web Development\MongoDB_Practice\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:313:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at emit (events.js:169:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mazic\Dropbox\Information System\CS602 Server Site Web Development\MongoDB_Practice\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:260:12)
    at g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\mazic\Dropbox\Information System\CS602 Server Site Web Development\MongoDB_Practice\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:162:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

and Here is my code:

```
"use strict";
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const dbUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/cs602';

MongoClient.connect(dbUrl,  (err, db) => {
    if (err)
    {throw err}else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to',
            db.s.databaseName);
    }
    // Do database operations
    db.close();
});
```

Here is my file structure:
[image]

I am new to node.js as well as mongodb, does anyone can help me with this? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: In the most common case this means that either mongodb isn't running or it was started on another port. You should check you mongo db configuration file and also check if you have already started the server

Comment: You also might wanna check the mongodb logs as well as these questions on troubleshooting mongodb problems:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245805/unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-error-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017-a

and 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245805/unable-to-connect-to-mongodb-error-couldnt-connect-to-server-127-0-0-127017-a

Comment: @VasilDininski Thank you so much! I found the resolution in those links you give me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error could be caused by the MongoDB's bind IP setting. You can check MongoDB's config file. But the truth is i don't know is located in Windows systems.

In my case, the bind IP is set to localhost address, just as following:

```
# /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I made it!